# Visual Studio 2017 Mark/Select block with solid background color

Tags: c++, visual-studio, select, colors, editor

Is there anyway inside VS2017 to

***a)*** mark a piece of code with a solid background color ie to know where block starts and where it ends without loosing its color focus when the cursor moves ?

***b)*** to select a piece of code with a solid background color for edge to edge without white spaces inside that ? Current selection leaves whites inside statements and does not color for the 1st column 'till the last one. See below. I installed Visual Assist but it does not seem to do the job.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it depends on the setting for "Virtual space".

Without it you only have the program code and the cursor never moves beyond the line end. With virtual space the entire window is active and will also be marked edge to edge when selecting lines.

[image]

Comment: Excellent !! Thank you ! Anyway to mark a section with a background color that will not dissapear when cursor moves ?